# Configuring AssociationField deafault property in EasyAdmin3

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin, easyadmin3

I have a question - is here a possibility to configure AssociationField to work with specific property. i.e:

I have a Subscription Entity with a many-to-one relation to User, User has a __toString() method, that returns username, and it is used across the application, so I can't change it. In the 'create Subscription' form, I have AssociationField::new('user'), where I'm able to find User by his name.

But this is inconvenient, since, when I need to create a Subscription, many users with same names pop up. Instead, I want to be able to search Users by ID, or email.

Is there a way to override default behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `AssociationField` is made using Symfony **EntityType**. If you look into the form type used by this field.

```
//AssociationField.php
public static function new(string $propertyName, $label = null): self
{
    return (new self())
    //...
        ->setFormType(EntityType::class)
    //...
```

It means that you can use every options from it. [See more here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html).

In your case, it's quite easy modifying your label by either defining another property or a callback.

Then you can use the `->setFormTypeOption()` to modify the entity type option.

So if you want to use a callback function to define a custom label:

```
AssociationField::new('user')
    ->setFormTypeOption('choice_label', function ($user) {
        return $user->getEmail();
    });
```

Or using php 7.4 arrow function:

```
AssociationField::new('user')
    ->setFormTypeOption('choice_label', fn($user) => $user->getEmail());
```

---

You can also define the email property as label:

```
AssociationField::new('user')
    ->setFormTypeOption('choice_label', 'email');
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. One improvement though, in case someone will want to copy paste - callback function lacks 'return'.

Comment: Oh my bad, I will edit it. At first I only wrote with an arrow function which do not use a return. It's fixed.